# Clear the graph and free the GPU memory in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training multiple models sequentially, which will be memory-consuming if I keep all models without any cleanup. However, I am not aware of any way to the graph and free the GPU memory in Tensorflow 2.x.

#### What I've tried but not working

`tf.keras.backend.clear_session` does not work in my case as I've defined some custom layers

`tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph` does not work either.

Comment: Have you tried del model before tf.keras.backend.clear_session?

Comment: I did not use `keras.model` I defined a custom training loop

Answer (score 1):

Few workarounds to avoid the memory growth. Use either one

1.

```
del model 

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

gc.collect()
```

2. Enable `allow_growth` (e.g. by adding `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true` to the environment). This will prevent TF from allocating all of the GPU memory on first use, and instead "grow" its memory footprint over time.
3. Enable the new CUDA malloc async allocator by adding `TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async` to the environment.

Comment: Hi,@TFer. Thanks for replying. Could you please shed more light on your methods? Based on my understanding, the first does not work as it calls `tf.keras` and my model include variables constructed using `tf.Variable`. I apply the second by default, but it does not seem to free memory as I wish. I'm not so sure how to process the third choice; you did not give any message about how to clear the constructed graph.